# How to create pictureboxes in code using OOP in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

Need help creating PictureBoxes Using Classes (if its possible)

Tried to create a class which sets the height, width, name and co-ordinates of a certain picturebox. Here are sections of my code:

```
Public Class Obj : Inherits PictureBox
    ReadOnly ObjHeight, ObjWidth, ObjX, ObjY As Integer
    Public ObjName

    Public Sub New(myHeight, myWidth, newX, newY, newName)
        ObjHeight = myHeight
        ObjWidth = myWidth
        ObjX = newX
        ObjY = newY
        ObjName = newName

        ObjName = New PictureBox With {
            .Height = ObjHeight,
            .Width = ObjWidth,
            .Left = ObjX,
            .Top = ObjY,
            .BackColor = Color.Red
        }
        Controls.Add(ObjName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I input:

```
Dim newObj = New Obj(200, 100, 150, 150, "newObj")
```

The code runs but it doesn't output a picturebox on the form. I've tried debugging but it outputs no errors. Is it becuase im trying to create a picturebox seperate from the place im suppost to? Any help would be appreciated, scold me.

Comment: What controls collection exactly is this adding the ObjName too?  There doesn't appear to be any reference to the actually form here.  Guessing you're calling this somewhere within a form, I wonder if you might be better off moving that in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, you have to add the control to the form's `Controls` collection. I know you have this line:

```
Controls.Add(ObjName)
```

But it's not right. It does NOT refer to the form's Controls collection. Rather, it refers to the `Controls` collection of your new `Obj` object (inherited from the base `PictureBox` type, which inherited it from the base `Control` type). And `ObjName` was previously set as a string, rather than a Control... which **should** cause a compile error, and if it doesn't it implies you are not using `Option Strict`, which is *very bad*. This is also implied by the lack of type definitions for the constructor arguments, which again is **very bad**.

Either way, *you should just remove this line*, as it's not accomplishing what you think. If you'd had `Option Strict` (or `Option Infer`) on, you'd have already found this.

So, again, you need to add this control to form's controls collection. And to do that, you need a reference to the form. We have two options. The first is adding it after creation:

```
Dim newObj As New Obj(200, 100, 150, 150, "newObj")
Me.Controls.Add(newObj)
```

The other option is providing the constructor with a reference for the form:

```
Public Sub New(myHeight As Integer, myWidth As Integer, newX As Integer, newY As Integer, newName As String, parent As Control)
```

Note I also fixed the type definitions here (because you really should consider the code **broken** without them). Then, later in the method, you can use the new `parent` argument like this:

```
parent.Controls.Add(Me)
```

This works even though I defined `parent` as a `Control` rather than any kind of form, because the base `Form` type also inherits from `Control`. It also lets you be creative and use things other than the form as the parent, such as container controls within a form, like a GroupBox, Panel, or FlowLayoutPanel.

---

The second issue is this line:

```
ObjName = New PictureBox With {
```

You **do not want to create a PictureBox instance here**, because your `Obj` type inherits from PictureBox... *it already IS a PictureBox*.

So we're left with this:

```
Public Sub New(myHeight As Integer, myWidth As Integer, newX As Integer, newY As Integer, newName As String, parent As Control)
    ObjHeight = myHeight
    ObjWidth = myWidth
    ObjX = newX
    ObjY = newY
    ObjName = newName

    Height = ObjHeight
    Width = ObjWidth
    Left = ObjX
    Top = ObjY
    BackColor = Color.Red

    parent.Controls.Add(Me)
End Sub
```

---

We can now take this one level further. Understanding the new `Obj` type already is a `PictureBox`, there's no more need at all for the ObjHeight, ObjWidth, ObjX, or ObjY fields.

So we can reduce it again:

```
Public Class Obj : Inherits PictureBox

    Public Sub New(myHeight As Integer, myWidth As Integer, newX As Integer, newY As Integer, newName As String, parent As Control)
        Height = myHeight
        Width = myWidth
        Left = newX,
        Top = NewY,
        BackColor = Color.Red
        Name = newName

        parent.Controls.Add(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Finally, I question the need for a new `Class` at all. Instead, I would merely add a method to the existing form:

```
Private Sub AddPictureBox(myHeight As Integer, myWidth As Integer, newX As Integer, newY As Integer, newName As String)
    Dim newBox As New PictureBox With {
            .Height = ObjHeight,
            .Width = ObjWidth,
            .Left = ObjX,
            .Top = ObjY,
            .BackColor = Color.Red
            .Name = newName
        }
    Me.Controls.Add(newBox)
End Sub
```

This is even better OOP, since what we're really describing is a behavior for your new Form.